# very slow wifi after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, intel-wireless

I upgraded yesterday from ubuntu 13.04 to ubuntu 13.10 and now my wifi connection is incredibly slow.
    ping google.com 
takes upto 270 ms with 46% packet loss

edit: It appears that this issue is intermittent. However my other laptop on the same network was working at normal speed throughout which should rule out my connection.

Comment: Try to plug directly into your router and do the test back. Also, you are saying that it's because of the ubuntu update, do you have proof or did you do a test right before the installation ?

Comment: tested, my connection is perfectly usable when plugged in. I upgraded over wifi and didn't have any issues, so it looks suspicious.

Comment: So, is it ok or there's still a problem ?

Comment: yes, the wireless connection is still unusable

Comment: I found this http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/  if it doesn't help, then I'm sorry and I hope you'll fix your problem.

Comment: thanks, but I'm afraid I don't even have the iwlagn module

Comment: 13.10 is beyond end of life, upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: It wasn't in October 2013.

Comment: @DavidFoerster OK, well, probably some clean up is indicated. Not sure why such an old question was resurrected.