# Another 13.10 Wireless Issue

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

I'm aware there are quite a few threads out there discussing wireless connectivity issues, and I can assure you I've read them. But I'm still having problems after following through all of those.

My problem is this. My wifi is slow to the point of not working, and drops connection every few minutes. What's more strange than that is that, when I speedtest, I get these weird spikes in speed, up and down, up and down.

[wifi spikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovhAP.png)

I've tried the things listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368077/very-slow-wifi-after-upgrading-from-13-04-to-13-10), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363126/slow-wifi-after-upgrading-kubuntu-13-04-to-13-10), [and here](http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/). None of these have resolved the issue.

I'm aware you guys are going to need wireless card info and stuff, but I'm not sure the exact commands to run/stuff to give you, so please let me know that and I'll update the question with any pertinent info.

Thanks for your time, this has been driving me nuts for days now. I should mention that the connection is fine when I'm: using wired connection, using windows, using another computer in the house. However, the problem persists at my university as well, so I'm pretty sure it isn't just my router.

Output of lshw -C network:

```
    *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c0
   serial: dc:0e:a1:b8:21:13
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:54 memory:f0300000-f033ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Comment: Using the info in the 3rd link seems an odd choice when you don't even know how to find out what wireless adapter you have. It's specific to an atheros model, which he doesn't even specify in the article. Be careful what you find in web searches. You may get a better answer if you post a question in ubuntuforums, maybe not. That's where I've gone for wireless problems. Anyway, enter this in terminal ... sudo lshw -C network ... and post the output. That's a start.

Comment: What you posted is ethernet, not wireless.